# Throttling an API that 429s after too many requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, throttling, rate-limiting

I'm trying to make several requests to the [BoardGameGeek (BGG) API](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/BGG_XML_API2) and after a certain amount of requests within a certain time frame, I get timed out (status code 429). I've tried a couple of libraries to try and get this to work.

I've tried using the [**simple-rate-limiter**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-rate-limiter) library as below, but this didn't work because BGG seems pretty aggressive with their rate limiting and they don't publish official limits anyways.

```js
    /* simple-rate-limiter initialization (https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-rate-limiter) */
    const limit = require('simple-rate-limiter');
    const request = limit(require('request')).to(10).per(1000);

    const fetchStatistics = async (game) => {
        /* Fetching the statistics from a separate API, because the base API doesn't include stats */
        const url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=' + game.$.objectid + '&stats=1';
        request(url, (err, res, body) => { // simple-rate-limiter making the request
            const xml = body;
            return XML2JS.parseString(xml, (err, result) => { //XML2JS library call
                console.log(result);
            })
        })
    }
```

Then I tried using the **[oibackoff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oibackoff)** library in conjunction with simple-rate-limiter as seen below, but still no luck.

```js
    /* simple-rate-limiter initialization (https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-rate-limiter) */
    const limit = require('simple-rate-limiter');
    const request = limit(require('request')).to(10).per(1000);

    /* oibackoff initialization (https://www.npmjs.com/package/oibackoff) */
    const backoff = require('oibackoff').backoff({
        algorithm: 'exponential',
        delayRatio: 1,
        maxTries: 0,
    });

    const fetchStatistics = async (game) => {
        /* Fetching the statistics from a separate API, because the base API doesn't include stats */
        const url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=' + game.$.objectid + '&stats=1';

        backoff(request, url, (err, res, body) => { // simple-rate-limiter making the request
            console.log(res.statusCode);
            const xml = res.body;
            return XML2JS.parseString(xml, (err, result) => {
                console.log(result);
            })
        })
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Should I be using a different library/approach?

---

Side note: I also tried **[request-rate-limiter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-rate-limiter)**, but I couldn't get the syntax to work with my project.

Comment: If you're still getting 429's, maybe you just need to keep changing the numbers until this no longer happens. Start with 1 request every 10 seconds and report back.

Comment: You might also be limited by the fact that you are using that cors-anywhere service. If there's others doing the same thing via cors-anywhere, you all share the same limits. It's not a good idea to use it for anything serious.

Comment: Yeah, slowing the requests WAY down will work, but for a collection with ~600 requests it'll take hours to load at that rate. My main concern with this question is if I'm misusing the `oibackoff` library. It doesn't seem to back off when it encounters a 429. It just keeps hammering on with requests.

Comment: The thing is, if you more or less found the limit, there's no way to go beyond that anyway. Exponential backoff will likely be slower even if you do get it to work.

Plus you are still sharing your pool of requests with everyone else who's using cors-anywhere, which is something you didn't address.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The cors-anywhere github does mention that the URL I'm using is for demo only purposes. I've hosted my own instance on Heroku and will continue testing.

Comment: I've self hosted the cors-anywhere repo on my own Heroku dyno, so now that is now eliminated as a bottleneck. Yet I'm still getting 429s after awhile, so I'm back to focusing on whether I've set up `oibackoff` and `simple-rate-limiter` correctly.

How would I use `oibackoff` with a `fetch.then` paradigm? I don't understand how to do that looking at this library's documentation. I'd like to test this to eliminate `simple-rate-limiter`.

Comment: Exponential back off is not better if the API has a fixed rate limit. You should try to get as close as possible to their rate limit. exponential backoff will double the timeout for every error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is specifically for the [BoardGameGeek API](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/BGG_XML_API2).

So instead of doing a bunch of individual requests such as:
`/xmlapi2/thing?stats=1&id=188920`
`/xmlapi2/thing?stats=1&id=174476`

You can batch them all into one request like this:
`/xmlapi2/thing?stats=1&id=188920,174476`

This means that you're only sending off 1 request and will not get rate limited.
I did find out that this still does fail if you attach over ~1200 game ids though. The server responds with `414 Request-URI Too Large`.
Here's an [example](https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?stats=1&id=250621,257668,226255,279307,279306,271447,187104,175263,253618,192458,271512,432,68448,173346,302260,239472,172818,5,231398,202408,267814,267813,183231,98315,191189,267127,281946,264647,2272,230085,31260,247367,256442,161970,6249,226089,181293,48726,250355,234487,228959,244738,245704,39339,124742,17329,212388,271530,262135,250834,142271,13122,175254,174614,74,58253,814,283393,140934,179803,144734,236457,256390,222862,15987,285773,225729,154825,246150,160432,254713,276923,69789,138233,108784,223762,273284,55253,248490,223201,175418,286658,225449,231581,446,162,127506,10093,230802,256226,287954,266164,199223,254585,170825,269917,293,206540,27225,223740,251247,224678,204175,2458,173776,234477,59936,39375,288781,268471,298528,89409,278305,165950,271528,243780,235533,10547,258036,34219,171233,226445,187383,235555,165952,277927,230244,148282,265316,156858,253861,262215,4168,3427,206504,170216,195856,27490,245710,244331,274688,11,261529,170922,276622,157973,252556,131835,166286,206175,148767,335,139898,181161,257726,130393,172308,192735,275913,127505,203102,137909,149853,201006,172081,11416,552,193681,284229,38032,171499,69120,214,246761,275916,199383,40270,238992,264660,41,5048,176651,232824,159503,208804,219509,171131,255455,36989,1126,269789,822,4390,256065,7717,16216,145014,262562,231484,245934,252712,233006,263918,194233,194233,242409,71906,238638,114903,266141,38386,256569,84876,213370,155426,279135,228504,245824,57390,194286,13,244144,67239,125921,218129,67453,102794,284818,175117,242574,232832,209685,218479,248900,267378,227072,172287,256507,196026,245598,189184,224830,229638,240567,251420,230916,25695,239188,221122,5432,167283,478,267370,133528,214880,162152,240465,201808,216132,34297,283289,262211,252261,1294,1561,198328,178900,220775,249821,220774,198773,238972,245638,95945,196240,264982,192934,5782,268252,269160,158899,118174,147151,247314,124361,112,2961,2719,190073,140236,269511,269595,277662,98351,269725,39463,204027,257380,131357,260382,180674,187653,230528,163656,284083,138026,230059,215371,264586,256570,273092,244274,192457,246784,228133,280480,269618,253344,175541,197321,275973,38437,226213,223049,28259,143986,202977,105602,289802,208134,193877,111124,193670,101685,101685,184522,150376,177921,156129,225694,283649,169654,104162,223726,256788,9061,152162,194594,230267,216734,244271,266966,184917,270377,170477,220624,221194,483,146597,258244,225316,91312,256382,218580,39856,186995,172164,179182,199793,5737,36218,209418,253786,152757,232090,124548,158267,215311,218637,217554,193840,254191,232219,212378,172866,126206,235655,1042,226501,272993,283748,184704,172933,172540,136356,194880,232980,205831,257415,263317,244916,255618,36235,283355,262208,45315,153745,207062,134596,279254,229491,131366,100423,146021,286431,216403,90050,68425,228378,83157,171339,36554,175621,50685,131121,196354,88594,282291,253214,206299,249381,206718,133848,270960,199792,1159,155703,201248,201825,277003,253074,163976,201846,272682,184247,172225,176371,254994,218639,188530,249670,294233,140218,13823,220780,135779,232918,293889,209280,254193,216600,223040,221230,271045,231664,231666,231665,256801,277597,198609,230591,96704,177736,847,163839,200954,257733,240744,226605,233020,231991,138161,75449,227162,206941,173784,157354,199478,100901,216597,244609,261165,223215,275969,256478,204574,256701,258,175324,159504,280896,256802,132758,172,144567,136063,65244,245271,72376,302723,287941,37904,244049,214032,288169,108155,245645,119506,276880,66188,248956,197443,258308,203430,253743,246693,181279,171273,258389,27787,220308,248443,137811,31481,159492,2921,179701,229218,275530,103343,180602,179259,176914,42776,137669,145393,257321,286215,30539,120447,193248,258665,241245,253719,118705,37046,259897,257273,226356,258444,166650,21985,176,246192,265188,214898,293556,207207,192547,217553,184346,294237,132620,13230,278120,175219,195539,265399,292795,234120,230542,238182,255615,192508,93,142992,193738,57201,156501,168054,212402,254513,171668,173804,256159,31808,4143,250458,251890,269144,227254,233848,158600,216381,197320,234,194626,223750,199042,200058,257205,228234,106217,186721,119639,131904,6887,227789,288876,382,224272,272132,164529,243231,195314,231554,252892,228944,198994,79067,261979,8203,302267,240167,171261,260332,245444,255805,207336,218050,169256,239621,202026,159536,216070,287219,159087,176898,176898,177524,235690,244995,219232,191894,191862,255674,246228,154203,217776,95893,144239,168996,31594,252323,233678,215308,181797,261403,63888,285895,206051,42939,174611,161882,158548,271088,194688,250963,231558,204755,176494,185589,148949,235488,246709,271324,271046,54043,253215,193621,229954,191687,8098,247360,174991,245431,254640,228425,200147,232254,183251,274432,198190,191055,252446,122515,257501,212516,215614,250561,3699,205826,160499,70323,126996,107529,204583,281960,253568,223953,154841,252402,181810,247733,227758,171879,278989,183420,266083,1219,228882,191681,160851,29368,210052,153479,220784,129437,146197,275467,140620,256831,260757,196976,254017,104617,241266,236301,268936,65781,40237,136991,770,169550,1536,823,20437,110327,203993,50,197707,158339,198525,254399,129622,129622,196326,66,242804,228169,245643,1,143884,175239,217671,96848,248763,180157,283863,9440,164198,230080,258041,165948,199,176734,276025,9590,283948,29223,230361,285774,272541,255012,139030,159581,211734,235839,2392,280453,224997,203624,268493,209010,193214,266304,230383,10630,175861,244794,25292,230933,19301,255639,114991,166109,559,248861,268677,239840,151347,200610,244992,225818,197433,109932,285533,118,173115,251622,238393,255526,209001,246696,245053,213862,36345,4209,280131,197414,122298,175199,214293,162315,182062,267945,174925,171211,1927,146735,112869,31920,112991,208256,144325,171199,129359,198776,229640,164031,180816,213670,86955,234396,191004,226320,181304,269537,915,234691,244191,275215,249746,54433,257836,253106,157809,171662,255990,271297,187617,246663,256643,280812,72321,290733,245058,205716,157413,232478,208895,272697,244711,257633,279869,8522,13511,181615,234216,217449,187347,269752,102148,294693,233676,158883,138704,194879,25554,284435,231567,206448,65515,234277,249505,273477,231733,260156,123219,283867,5206,279169,94571,230089,211940,211940,270445,184267,276004,281152,251412,1234,179275,263155,147949,160477,3737,255507,245950,284949,174646,200924,287084,222542,172931,1491,23953,176803,117838,37120,154003,152237,152237,223278,266810,239464,140163,30549,260428,192153,234671,150658,248167,248584,217861,141572,241066,207010,280136,284429,266524,15110,9006,2593,257966,144041,163412,256960,128780,257732,1797,169215,155465,97803,252479,148205,231032,210274,218603,209282,98229,284108,197571,246200,271036,224060,244505,232520,256730,73538,218996,125548,99808,252929,204879,23094,232201,155440,257077,251660,163119,247576,274960,226264,172385,254619,249500,137155,180974,207783,2651,203780,106662,268251,87890,209945,6549,182604,218179,181796,219708,201992,3076,228341,54221,114050,67928,1419,187988,36648,215469,266830,244521,176396,131200,681,232043,217372,274093,624,25669,39813,131260,208775,12,254386,231876,28143,243696,253635,256728,170042,210908,251678,245654,177639,42452,235071,256623,250878,208024,24310,33451,66510,142402,212662,244258,249578,193668,36946,222906,161417,244228,294230,170604,135116,282287,41114,128882,128882,34887,104363,241831,91514,220926,221372,194232,51,118695,202583,205896,181,1829,126789,262114,66056,257759,227515,234093,232666,203215,18,231477,231476,240006,235653,255683,254613,169426,195161,237182,201,165986,168788,266722,285265,252854,9220,168215,268680,199561,117960,35395,158900,234101,175086,276830,97824,194655,244330,230266,148533,372,172235,234846,256669,438,320,169786,177515,108745,265683,188834,200847,216428,25021,159868,199907,250951,247143,223855,146408,102652,228855,24068,159405,279928,112092,253087,229741,15062,246297,200359,6284,157969,204305,298352,220517,75547,183361,220672,256967,233247,178450,202426,257066,278553,278554,188614,280281,149910,23329,254976,216629,40692,97786,246684,122522,162559,227893,113289,38054,271038,174837,254018,223327,255255,223376,181819,235767,235014,2407,37196,260407,38453,242302,299074,142079,266179,243358,14535,220547,252277,221832,196105,66505,256313,171129,162886,149119,148228,63268,63268,63268,63268,117995,227545,166384,229006,1035,287780,199497,243993,221233,102104,4095,230253,268276,193737,193949,117985,178613,79127,248567,5258,271896,1897,262262,245357,223770,224937,2770,27833,121410,162007,230570,205459,2680,34635,20436,137550,251854,1917,1917,221643,257669,202584,91534,132799,233312,207910,265684,123260,299372,93260,231960,257445,170917,201971,234316,224907,162286,16933,16933,276641,139443,260383,2653,192291,133473,271869,204886,244141,203716,257667,248002,475,153,70919,130176,34119,238889,27627,908,25261,286096,129556,146278,276416,236709,247694,221369,46213,173761,95386,229853,120677,20022,167791,272427,186695,270138,226322,226634,257411,1943,188920,159011,175961,145371,20806,282438,182028,503,209951,53953,116998,215341,9209,14996,205125,225244,253284,31627,202670,22825,42,54,34373,581,276924,155708,148951,257283,201921,180852,244536,227693,265736,258723,123540,257197,268250,261901,236365,235360,235344,257198,256479,192135,294348,210900,35815,216632,226146,255633,283864,129091,102680,175293,163805,163805,257527,216439,242639,202582,282171,36407,258104,242325,148291,256303,281442,240822,257073,1410,15261,16992,124172,229414,196392,233078,12493,206904,12333,222887,286892,134352,234621,234438,126163,16986,31479,266421,34969,219100,268682,38159,247763,217085,1690,179172,159566,274637,2223,234190,260635,226588,286829,170561,276801,218920,269526,257058,170416,120906,208360,189453,2596,27532,194690,231223,280143,257076,143981,239877,35505,191301,266842,257769,247980,249259,253499,206803,195560,274364,333,262543,48979,31016,264806,166859,233867,229265,233206,245422,232405,201054,190082,93563,218126,146910,244654,266192,222853,20100,71655,203411,274296,208480,186690,179245,192351,270635,163602,234828,247191,2243,213893,247185,244114,224271,43022,283294,220741,6830,180853,2247,284107,249289,246754,113924,62871,29387,231673,79312,155633,10167,41627,257204,261431) of that error.

If you need more then 1200 then you'll probably have to split the game ids and make multiple requests so that you only request 1200 at a time.